# Data Import in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

SQL Server Express does not have the Tasks -> Import Data option that other editions of SQL Server has. Has anyone come across a free tool to import data?

I understand I can use the bulk import but I have run into a security issue with it and would like a quick and a dirty way of importing a csv file to a sql express table.

Comment: May be [SSMS: How to import (Copy/Paste) data from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61012585/6165594) can help (If you don't want to use `BULK NSERT` or don't have permissions for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the SQL Server 2005 Toolkit add on, do a full instal of the components and you will get a free copy of the DTS Wizard, the equivalent of what came in other versions.

Comment: assuming your talking Version 2005

Answer (score 1):

Check out this forum post, has two good solutions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/546f4407-0aa4-4b04-96f3-e6f0ba39a9d1/

BCP and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit